# Javascript SIP library sip.js and JsSIP differences?

Tags: webrtc, sip, sip-server

I have three doubts that require some clear explanation .

> 1. A clear purpose of those two JavaScript SIP library in relation to Webrtc and     sip signalling.
> 2. Difference between Sip.js and JsSIP JavaScript SIP Library.
> 3. Does IP PBX means sip server or sip proxy as well

Comment: Useful article comparing multiple libraries: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324778752_Comparative_analysis_of_SIP-libraries_Improvements_of_JsSIP_library

Answer (score 1):

1. Those are WEBRTC SIP libraries, the purpose is to add voice and video communication to a web app.
2. No major difference. both have more less the same features.
3. IP PBX means a business phone system, and a SIP server is the software that send the call to the phone device.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across those both libraries today.
I figured out, that you can't use them with your General SIP-Provider, if the Provider didn't support `Sip over Websocket`.

But you can use it with your SIP-Server / PBX (like Asterisk or [FreeSWITCH](https://freeswitch.com/)), or with an Sip-Proxy like http://oversip.net/ (you also can have a look at the Outbound-Info for more Information: http://oversip.net/documentation/misc/outbound/